# GPU quotas not showing in request list (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, quota

Im trying to start an VM instance on GCP which needs to have a GPU but when I start the instance I dont have the allowed number of GPUs. It asks me to request via the Quouta page. But the GPU quota  is not showing up in this page.

I have upgraded my free-trial account and I have tired what ever was suggested in the other SO posts i could find something along these lines:

- Incognito mode
- Other browser
- Going to Quota page by both: "Compute Engine->Quotas" and "IAM & Admin->
- Some filtering suggested on another post

Anyone figured out how to request these GPU Quotas?

**Edit** Added GCP to title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we currently are diagnosing an intermittent issue on this page that is causing the experience you describe for some users. We expect a fix to be available in a couple days (hopefully by end of August). In the meantime, users may post to the [gce-discussion Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gce-discussion) in order to contact a support engineer who can manually assist you.